# Cannot answer protected questions with 97 reputation

Tags: support, answers, protected-questions

I can't seem to be able to answer protected questions here on Meta, where I have 97 reputation (as of writing). The text says that I must have at least 10 reputation, but I obviously have more.

Comment: Yay! My third duplicate. I just love having "[duplicate]" appended to my question title...

Comment: I'm assuming that is sarcastic, but I don't know why. Why would it bother you so much to have a question marked as a duplicate? Seriously, I don't get why people are so offended by this.

Comment: @CodyGray It is not sarcasm. I originally put "literally" at the end but then removed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears as though you have earned an association bonus of 100 reputation here (from earning 200 reputation from another Stack Exchange site). When calculating the amount of reputation necessary to answer a protected question, **the 100-point association bonus is ignored**, which means that you only have 1 reputation if you didn't get the association bonus, which is less than 10, which means you can't answer protected questions yet. You can when you get 110 reputation.

Comment: Instead of explaining confusing message it's better to fix it [Make reputation message when answering protected questions less ambiguous](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270842)