# I think the notice on protected question should link to "on this site"

Tags: discussion, reputation, hyperlinks, protected-questions

So this is what is written in the notice in protected questions:

> This question is protected to prevent "thanks!", "me too!", or spam answers by new users. To answer it, you must have earned at least 10 [reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) on this site.

In my opinion, the phrase *on this site* is more important than the word *reputation*, therefore it should have the link (I have no comment on the linkification of that word though). This is based on my experience that although I had 101 rep on a site, I still didn't have 10 rep earned on that site, and this confused me for a while.

Comment: It links to explanation about reputation. So it makes 100% sense to have the word "reputation" as the link. If anything the whole "reputation on this site" can be the link.

Comment: related: [Make reputation message when answering protected questions less ambiguous](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270842/make-reputation-message-when-answering-protected-questions-less-ambiguous)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the "reputation" link goes to the "what's reputation?" page, it makes sense to keep the link there. I think a better way to emphasize the per-site-ness would be to bold "earned" and "on this site." It requires no more words, and it makes it more apparent that you have to actually gain the points (not just from the join bonus) and that they have to be from this site.

> This question is protected to prevent "thanks!", "me too!", or spam answers by new users. To answer it, you must have **earned** at least 10 [reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) **on this site**.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, having a link on the words "this site" is a bit pointless. Where would you link it to? back to the site's frontpage?

I do agree it could be a good idea to emphasize them though - perhaps by making them **bold** or *italic*.

Comment: link to a meta post perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

I really wonder how many work it would be to let the message show 110 if the user has the association bonus and 10 if the user hasn't. Of course, one should remove the earned part if this is implemented.

Note that it is in fact not even completely accurate, since you have not earned your first 1 reputation, so in fact you only have to earn 9 reputation.